# Django testing - ImportError/ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, django, importerror

I'm working through the Django tutorial, currently on part 5 — testing, when I go to run the test through the terminal I keep getting the following error message:

```
(venv) My-MacBook-Pro:mysite Me$ python manage.py test polls
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
E
======================================================================
ERROR: mysite.polls (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: mysite.polls
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/unittest/loader.py", line 470, in _find_test_path
    package = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/unittest/loader.py", line 377, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite.polls'


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

I'm not really sure what's going on here, the test code is copy and pasted directly out off the Django site.

Test Code(polls/test.py):

```
import datetime

from django.test import TestCase
from django.utils import timezone

from .models import Question


class QuestionModelTests(TestCase):

    def test_was_published_recently_with_future_question(self):
        """
        was_published_recently() returns False for questions whose pub_date
        is in the future.
        """
        time = timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=30)
        future_question = Question(pub_date=time)
        self.assertIs(future_question.was_published_recently(), False)
```

My tree:

[image: Picture of my dir tree]

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Check whether your local Django version is the same as your tutorial first.

Comment: They are. Tutorial = 3.0, local = 3.0.6

Comment: may be `Polls` instead of `polls` ?

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally capitalized Polls for clarification/easier reading it.

Comment: If I'm reading correctly, you have two directories titled mysite, an overarching one, and the mysite directory that holds your settings.py file. Most likely Django is trying to import Polls from the latter rather than the former. I'm not sure what test is exactly going on here, but you may need to change import mysite.polls to import polls, or from . import polls

Comment: Hey Alex, I updated the tree with a picture to make it more clear. I was thinking along the same lines as you. I attempted to change the mysite outer dir to a different name which threw a different error along with the original. To change import mysite.polls would require me to change Django source code no? –